# how to properly populate DataSet twice (after empty set)

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, dataset

I've got a SqlConnection with a sqlquery that may not bring any results.  On the rare occasion this happens, I have another sqlquery and another connection to the database.  There has to be a better way to do this, no?

On a side note, is this best to close the connection after .Fill?  I assume so, but haven't seen it used anywhere.

I'm still getting started in C#/.Net -- Thanks!

```
SqlConnection dbSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(--);
SqlDataAdapter dbSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, dbSqlConnection);
DataSet dbDataSet = new DataSet();
dbSqlDataAdapter.Fill(dbDataSet, "popGrid");
dbSqlConnection.Close();

if (dbDataSet.Tables["popGrid"].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    SqlDataAdapter newSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery2, dbSqlConnection);
    newSqlDataAdapter.Fill(dbDataSet, "popGrid");
    dbSqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: And yes, always close your db connections - the database itself has a limited number of connections, so if too many are left open new connections will fail.

Comment: You need to have dbSqlConnection.Close after the if statement.  You only open the SqlConnection once, so it should be closed once.  And if you access it after it is closed, you'll get an exception thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, I think it's also ok if you connect to the DB twice after check the first result is empty. You don't have to make the two into one single query, unless this action(fetch data twice) is super frequent, or connecting to DB costs much time(e.g. you are in US and the DB is in UK,it's possible,right?)
And for the second question:

```
using (SqlConnection dbSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    //do things
}//the connection will be disposed automatically here
```

Comment: Excellent point.  This automatically calls .Dispose, which is the same as manually calling .Close (but better because it will close the connection, even if an exception is thrown).

Comment: Ah, that's great -- I remember reading about that but never investigated.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a single query which does:

```
Select * From SqlQuery1 Into TempTable1;

IF (SELECT Count(*) From TempTable1) = 0 BEGIN
  Select * From SqlQuery2;
ELSE
  Select * From TempTable1;
END
```

This is pseudo-code, as I haven't tested it and it is kind of on a whim.  Been a while since I've written queries.  So for homework, research how to use an if statement to test how to determine if a temp table has no rows, and then return a different query if it does.

Edit:

Putting both queries into a single query is negligibly better than calling two queries.  So it most likely isn't worth doing unless you have a really good reason to.

Comment: Well if you don't know if it will work, maybe you shouldn't post it as an answer?  PS it won't work.

Comment: Pseudo-code not work?  pseudo-code conveys a meaning but is not designed to work.  And it is only here until you post it as non-pseudo-code anyways.

Comment: But it can't be implemented in a way which satisfies the OPs requirements.  SQL queries cannot contain conditionals (stored procs can, but that's a different matter).

Comment: That sounds good.  I appreciate the answer and perhaps I'll use that as a backup.  But I'm more curious about the original question...  Thanks!